# templateHelpers in Marionette.CompositeView

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, marionette

I have no idea why this code is not working.
Reading the [documentation](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html),
the `templateHelpers` should be called.

My goal is to pass the `this.collection.length` to the template.

Any hints? thanks.

I am using Backbone.Marionette v0.9.5

---

```
return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    className: 'user-board',

    template: usersTemplate,

    itemView: userItemView,

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new UseList();
        this.collection.fetch();
    },

    appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
        collectionView.$el.find('ul.users-list').append(itemView.el);
    },

    templateHelpers: function () {
        console.log(this.collection.length);
    },

    serializeData: function () {
        return {
            weekly: this.options.weekly,
            users_length: this.collection.length // here the length is zero
                                           // after the fetch the length is > 0
                                           // but in template remains 0
        };
    }
});
```

---

To fix my issue I have to make the following...

```
    initialize: function () {
        _.bindAll(this, 'render');
        this.collection = new NewCollection();
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: this.render
        });
    }
```

Is there a better way to make it working?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Reading the [Marionette Documentation](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-12) `serializeData` method, which is the one using `mixinTemplateHelpers`, is only called on `Item View.render` method [here](http://derickbailey.github.com/backbone.marionette/docs/backbone.marionette.html#section-24) and in your current code you do not render at all

UPDATE:
This way everytime the collection receives new data it will update your view the new length

```
initialize: function () {
    _.bindAll(this, 'render');
    this.collection = new NewCollection();
    this.collection.fetch();
    this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);
}
```

Comment: Hi Claudiu, I updated my code in my question and I am pretty sure tok to render Item View. can you confirm it? thanks.

Comment: After checking your update I can confirm that you render your view on `fetch.success`. Even though you are fetching the collection on `CompositeView.initialize` your view does not wait for the fetching process to finish and when rendering it will render with 0, that is why you must have a `this.collection.bind('reset', this.render);` for the view to rerender when collection is changed. I updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

This code only declares the a view. Can you share the code the instantiates the view and displays it? `templateHelpers` will be called and the data passed to the template **when the template is rendered**. That is, you either need to show the view in a region which implicitly calls the `render` method on the view, or explicitly call the `render` method.

To be useful, `templateHelpers` should return an object. For instance:

```
templateHelpers: function() {
    return {colLength: this.collection.length};
}
```

One important thing to keep in mind: `fetch` trigger an AJAX request that is done asynchronously. If you want to wait for the `fetch` to succeed before rendering the view, then you need to use [Marionette.Async](https://github.com/derickbailey/backbone.marionette/blob/master/docs/marionette.async.md).

---

***Update based on the update question***

To avoid calling `render` from the view's `initialize` and only do it when `render` is called externally, change your code to:

```
return Marionette.CompositeView.extend({
    className: 'user-board',

    template: usersTemplate,

    itemView: userItemView,

    initialize: function () {
        this.collection = new UseList();
        var that = this;
        this.defer = $.Deferred();
        this.collection.fetch({
            success: that.defer.resolve,
            error: that.defer.resolve
        });
    },

    appendHtml: function (collectionView, itemView) {
        collectionView.$el.find('ul.users-list').append(itemView.el);
    },

    templateHelpers: function () {
        console.log(this.collection.length);
        // For greater flexibility and maintainability, don't override `serializeData`.
        return {
            weekly: this.options.weekly,
            users_length: this.collection.length
        };
    },

    render: function() {
        var that = this,
            args = arguments;
        $.when(this.defer).done(function() {
            Marionette.CompositeView.prototype.apply(that, args);
        });
    }
});
```

I'm resolving `this.render` both on success and error, otherwise if there is an error the view will never render (unless that's what you want).

Note that if you use Marionette.Async then you would return `this.defer` in the view's `beforeRender` and Marionette.Async would take care of delaying the rendering.

Also note that once `this.defer` is resolved, future renders will run when called as there is nothing to wait for, until `this.defer` has been reset programmatically.

Comment: +1 Hi Tony thanks for your response. I updated my code in my question. So please tell me, if in my case, there is a way to avoid using `Marionette.Async` or to it is the best option.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Marionette v1.0.3, I'm liking the pattern that rendering is handled automatically during a call to Region.show(), so I call that from a controller object which has the collection and passes it to the view on instantiation then shows the view. I don't even have to put this logic in a fetch success callback or explicitly bind to the 'reset' event, because the Marionette composite/collection view already knows to (re-)render itself on fetch success (which a debugger will show you).

Answer (score 0):

After using a setup like has been detailed, you can also use template helpers a bit more usefully than has been described so far.

**For example,**

If you simply drop in <%= functionName %> into the template where you are trying to get the number to show up visually on the front end page (since you want .length I see), marionette will simply do the work for you.

So like this:

```
--Template File--
<div id="followerCount"> <%= showCount %> </div>


--Helper Function in View--
templateHelpers: {
    showCount: function(){
                   return this.collection.length;
    } 
}
```

Hope that made sense or at least helps someone else perhaps looking for a simpler way to integrate database returned json to their templates.